# Work around the SQLite parameter limit in a select query

Tags: peewee

I have a GUI application with a list of people which contains the person's database id and their attributes. Something like this:

```
+----+------+
| ID | Name |
+----+------+
|  1 | John |
|  2 | Fred |
|  3 | Mary |
[...]
```

This list can be filtered, so the amount and type of people depend from time to time. To get a list of Peewee `Person` objects I first get the list of visible IDs and use the following query:

```
ids = [row[0] for row in store]
Person.select().where(Person.id.in_(ids))
```

Which in turn translates to the following SQL:

```
('SELECT "t1"."id", "t1"."name" FROM "person" AS "t1" WHERE ("t1"."id" IN (?, ?, ?, ...))', [1, 2, 3, ...])
```

This throws an `OperationalError: too many SQL variables` error on Windows with more than 1000 people. This is documented in the Peewee and SQLite docs. Workarounds given online usually relate to bulk inserts and ways to split the action in chunks. Is there any way to work around this limitation with the mentioned `SELECT ... WHERE ... IN` query?

Getting the separate objects in a list comprehension is too slow:

```
people = [Person.get_by_id(row[0]) for row in store]
```

Maybe split the list of IDs in max 1000 items, use the select query on each chunk and then combine those somehow?

Comment: Thanks for "Joining".

Comment: @danny117 I presume this is in reference to SQL JOIN. How could that be used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are the IDs coming from? The best answer is to avoid using that many parameters, of course. For example, if your list of IDs could be represented as a query of some sort, then you can just write a subquery, e.g.

```
my_friends = (Relationship
              .select(Relationship.to_user)
              .where(Relationship.from_user == me))
tweets_by_friends = Tweet.select().where(Tweet.user.in_(my_friends))
```

In the above, we could get all the user IDs from the first query and pass them en-masse as a list into the second query. But since the first query ("all my friends") is itself a query, we can just compose them. You could also use a JOIN instead of a subquery, but hopefully you get the point.

If this is not possible and you seriously have a list of >1000 IDs...how is such a list useful in a GUI application? Over 1000 anything is quite a lot of things.

To try and answer the question you asked -- you'll have to chunk them up. Which is fine. Just:

```
user_ids = list_of_user_ids
accum = []
# 100 at a time.
for i in range(0, user_ids, 100):
    query = User.select().where(User.id.in_(user_ids[i:i+100]))
    accum.extend([user for user in query])
return accum
```

But seriously, I think there's a problem with the way you're implementing this that makes it even necessary to filter on so many ids.

Comment: It's an application where the user can add/edit/remove people with some info for each person. It's up to them how many people they want to add. I didn't expect this either, but got some bugreports from users who did, so who am I to judge. At startup the entire `person` table is added to the treeview and the GUI framework is used to filter which rows are shown based on user settings. So no extra database queries are made for filtering. That means I have to get the list of currently shown people IDs through a list comprehension as shown in the question.